Access Azure keyvault secret properties from existing resource in Bicep
I'm looking for a solution to get secretUriWithVersion form an existing secret:
`resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' existing = {
name: '${kv}/${secretname}'
}
output keyvaultUri string = secret.properties.secretUriWithVersion`
This gives the following error:
The expression cannot be evaluated, because the identifier properties of the referenced existing resource including "name" cannot be calculated at the start of the deployment. In this situation, the accessible properties of "..." include "apiVersion", "id", "name", "type".bicep(BCP307)
I'm expecting the properties of the secret as it's already been provisioned earlier

please share the bicep code you tried @Øystein

Bicep Template used to create the KV
var keyVaultName = 'myKeyVaulttms'

var resourceGroupLocation = resourceGroup().location

var tenantId = subscription().tenantId

resource azureKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: resourceGroupLocation
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'standard'
      family: 'A'
    }
    accessPolicies: []
    tenantId: tenantId
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
      ipRules: []
      virtualNetworkRules: []
    }
    enableRbacAuthorization: false
  }
}

resource mainDbKeyVaultSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: azureKeyVault
  name: '1-dbConnectionString'
  properties: {
    value: 'test-secret'
  }
}

Get the existing key vault secret with version
resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2024-04-01-preview' existing = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}/1-dbConnectionString'
}

output secretValue string = secret.properties.secretUriWithVersion


